# In Hive, what is the difference between explode() and lateral view explode()

Tags: hive

Assume there is a table `employee`:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| col_name  |    data_type     |
+-----------+------------------+
| id        | string           |
| perf      | map<string,int>  |
+-----------+------------------+
```

and the data inside this table:

```
+-----+------------------------------------+--+
| id  |                perf                |
+-----+------------------------------------+--+
| 1   | {"job":80,"person":70,"team":60}   |
| 2   | {"job":60,"team":80}               |
| 3   | {"job":90,"person":100,"team":70}  |
+-----+------------------------------------+--+
```

I tried the following two queries but they all return the same result:

```
1. select explode(perf) from employee;
2. select key,value from employee lateral view explode(perf) as key,value;
```

The result:

`+---------+--------+--+
|   key   | value  |
+---------+--------+--+
| job     | 80     |
| team    | 60     |
| person  | 70     |
| job     | 60     |
| team    | 80     |
| job     | 90     |
| team    | 70     |
| person  | 100    |
+---------+--------+--+`

So, what is the difference between them? I did not find suitable examples. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your particular case both queries are OK. But you can't use multiple `explode()` functions without lateral view. So, the query below will fail:

```
select explode(array(1,2)), explode(array(3, 4))
```

You'll need to write something like:

```
select
    a_exp.a,
    b_exp.b
from (select array(1, 2) as a, array(3, 4) as b) t
lateral view explode(t.a) a_exp as a
lateral view explode(t.b) b_exp as b
```